# Wrong Time Zone in logs of Google Apps Scripts

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, timezone, google-apps

The Time Zone get from Date() in the script is correct, CEST (Central European Summer Time).  But the time zone reported from **View -> Logs** menu in the script editor is PDT (Pacific Daylight Time)

That happens whatever standalone scripts and spreadsheets scripts.

This is an *ad-hoc* example code:

```
  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUserLocale());
  Logger.log(Session.getScriptTimeZone());
  var d = new Date();
  Logger.log(d.toLocaleString());
```

> `[17-09-12 01:50:46:566 PDT] es`
>
> `[17-09-12 01:50:46:567 PDT] Europe/Paris`
>
> `[17-09-12 01:50:46:568 PDT] 12 de septiembre de 2017 10:50:46 CEST`

The Time Zone of the system is CEST.  The Time Zone in Google Calendar and GMail of the google account is CEST too.

Any explanation?

*P.S.*

Related but not the same issue that theese questions:

- [Time zones in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451292/time-zones-in-google-apps-script)
- [Google Apps Script formatDate using user's time zone instead of GMT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596933/google-apps-script-formatdate-using-users-time-zone-instead-of-gmt)
- [Google date on spreadsheet is different than date in script logger. Is this a time zone issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020486/google-date-on-spreadsheet-is-different-than-date-in-script-logger-is-this-a-ti?rq=1)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Hadn't noticed that before. I've just tried running a script with different user accounts and different script tz, and it looks like it's just a thing: the logging date is always PDT (maybe coz that's where Google's servers are???).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log & the execution transcript seem to use US/PDT, which would be consistent with Google's home time-zone. However, if you export the logs the times are rendered in the script time-zone. Here's an example from a script that emails me an execution log.

Logs from Script Editor `View`>`Logs`

```
[17-09-12 18:28:40:915 PDT] Export file created: '[redacted].csv' (id: [redacted])
[17-09-12 18:28:43:274 PDT] Archive file created: '[redacted] - 20170913112841+1000 - export.csv' (id: [redacted])
...etc, etc.
```

Same section of the log from the emailed transcript:

```
Wed Sep 13 11:28:40 AEST 2017 INFO: Export file created: '[redacted].csv' (id: [redacted])
Wed Sep 13 11:28:43 AEST 2017 INFO: Archive file created: '[redacted] - 20170913112841+1000 - export.csv' (id: [redacted])
...etc, etc.
```

Annoyingly, while the exported logs are in the correct tz, they're in that non-ISO format Google so likes to foist on us.

Comment: How can I export the log?

Comment: Just use Logger.getLog() to grab the log data & email it or write it to a file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Go to 'File > Project properties > Info tab' and set the timezone.

If you can't see the menu bar with 'File' etc, you're using the new editor.
You will need to click 'Use legacy editor' which will let you access the setting, then you can go back to the new editor.